# How to set the content-type when I render my own response in a CXF @WebMethod

Tags: java, cxf, content-type

I'm having problems setting the `Content-Type` when I do my own rendering inside of a CXF (v2.6.3) `@WebMethod`.

The following pattern works fine:

```java
@Path("/foo")
@WebService
public class FooService {
    @Path("/bar")
    @Produces({ "text/plain" })
    @GET
    @WebMethod
    public String bar() {
        return "hi";
    }
```

This returns `"hi"` to the http-client with a `Content-Type: Content-Type: text/plain` header which is what I expect.

However, when I try to do my own rendering by using the response `OutputStream`, `"hi"` is properly returned but the `@Produces` annotation is ignored and the default `text/xml` content-type is returned.  This is true even if I call `setContentType(...)` myself.

```java
@Path("/heartbeat2")
@Produces({ "text/plain" })
@WebMethod
@Get
public void heartbeat2() {
    HttpServletResponse response = messageCtx.getHttpServletResponse();
    response.getOutputStream().write("hi".getBytes());
    // fails with or without this line
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
}
```

Here's the output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 2
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Jetty(8.1.9.v20130131)

hi
```

Any idea how I can render my own output directly to the output-stream *and* set the content-type appropriately?   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with what you are doing. At the very least setting content-type in `HttpServletResponse` should work. Anyways, you can have more control over what you return if you use `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` . See if this works :

```
@Path("/foo")
@WebService
public class FooService {
    @Path("/bar")
    @GET
    @WebMethod
    public Response bar() {
        return Response.ok().type("text/plain").entity("hi").build();
    }
    ...
```